# "message": "expected string or bytes-like object",

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I want the total time taken by a session to get completed, but I am getting the above mentioned error, What do I need to change?

#MODEL

```
class User(models.Model):
    user = models.CharField(max_length=40)


class Sport(models.Model):
    Sports_Name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)


class Session(models.Model):
    Host = models.ForeignKey(MyUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='host')
    sports = models.ForeignKey(Sport, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Start_time = models.TimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, null=True)
    End_time = models.TimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, null=True)


class Gamification(models.Model):
    User_Name = models.ForeignKey(MyUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

#viewset

```
users = Gamification.objects.all()

b = []
for user in users:
    b.append({
        "User_Name": user.User_Name.user_name,
        'Session_Created': Session.objects.filter(Host=user.User_Name).count(),
        "Session_Joined": Session.objects.filter(Players_Participating=user.User_Name).count(),

        "Completion_Time(in days)": Session.objects.filter(End_time=user.User_Name),

    })

return Response({'success': b})
```

Comment: it's not clear what you're trying to do and also you've not mentioned any error.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `JsonResponse` instead of `Response`. If you want to send an array instead of JSON, do this:

```py
return JsonResponse(b, safe=False)
```

Comment: return JsonResponse(b, safe=False)
still same error is popping up